# Carbon: Get start and end date of week when knowing week in year and year

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

Carbon provides the function weekOfYear to get the week of the year as integer. However I need to go the other way round to get the a date based on the year + the week of the year.

```
Carbon::now()->weekOfYear(); // todays week of the year
```

E.g.

- year: 2016
- week of year: 42

As a result i need the start and end date of this given week. However i cannot find a fitting function in the Carbon docs

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Carbon is a wrapper for PHP's DateTime, so you can use [setISODate](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php):

```
$date = Carbon::now(); // or $date = new Carbon();
$date->setISODate(2016,42); // 2016-10-17 23:59:59.000000
echo $date->startOfWeek(); // 2016-10-17 00:00:00.000000
echo $date->endOfWeek(); // 2016-10-23 23:59:59.000000
```

Comment: use $date->copy()->startOfWeek() and $date->copy()->endOfWeek() in case you receive the same date object as startOfWeek.

Comment: This will fail with dates like `2021-01-01`. See my answer for a better approach

Comment: @FaizanAkramDar The OP asked for finding the information starting from the Year and Week Number, not an actual date. For 2021-01-01, that would be [2020 - 53](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2021)

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @return array{0: \DateTime, 1: \DateTime}
 */
public static function getWeekDates(\DateTimeInterface $selectedDate): array
{
    $daysFromMonday = (int) $selectedDate->format('N') - 1;

    $fromDate = \DateTimeImmutable::createFromInterface($selectedDate)->modify("-{$daysFromMonday} days");

    $toDate = $fromDate->modify('+6 days');

    return [
        \DateTime::createFromImmutable($fromDate),
        \DateTime::createFromImmutable($toDate),
    ];
}
```

This returns date of Monday and Sunday (iso week number).

If you wish to know dates of Sunday and Saturday, you can easily modify the function (replace `'N'` with `'w'` in `format`) and remove `-1`

Answer (score 0):

$WeekArray = array();

```
 $FirstDate = Carbon::now()->addYears(-2);
 $LastDate = Carbon::now()->addYears(2);

 while ($FirstDate <= $LastDate) {
    $WeekNumber = Carbon::parse($FirstDate)->weekOfYear;
    $WeekYear = Carbon::parse($FirstDate)->year;
    $StartOfWeek = Carbon::parse($FirstDate)->startOfWeek();
    $EndOfWeek = Carbon::parse($FirstDate)->endOfWeek(); 
    
    $WeekItem = new stdClass;
    $WeekItem->WeekNumber = $WeekNumber;
    $WeekItem->WeekYear = $WeekYear;
    $WeekItem->FirstDate = AppHelper::_DateFormatMysql($StartOfWeek);
    $WeekItem->LastDate = AppHelper::_DateFormatMysql($EndOfWeek);

    if (count($WeekArray) > 0) {
        if (collect($WeekArray)->where('WeekYear', $WeekItem->WeekYear)->where('WeekNumber', $WeekItem->WeekNumber)
                               ->where('FirstDate', $WeekItem->FirstDate)->where('LastDate', $WeekItem->LastDate)->count() == 0) 
        {
            array_push($WeekArray, $WeekItem);
        }
    }
    else {
        array_push($WeekArray, $WeekItem);
    }

    $FirstDate = Carbon::parse($FirstDate)->addDays(1);
 }
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.