# Display the first and last day of a (calendar) week

Tags: php, sql, date

In my database I have a table with consecutive dates. I group all dates to calendar weeks and display them in a table in my CSS.

Now i want to display also the first and the last day of the calendar week in my table.
Here is my code:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT WEEK(Date), Date FROM table GROUP BY WEEK(Date)");
    $result = $statement->execute();
    $count = 1;
    while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['WEEK(Date)']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Date']."</td>";
```

Currently there is only shown the first day of the calendar week.
I thought of duplicating `$row['Date']`and adding +6 (days) but the first dataset is not the first day of the week. So the first date range of the first calendar week would be wrong.
Does anyone has an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Carbon: Get start and end date of week when knowing week in year and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40156032/carbon-get-start-and-end-date-of-week-when-knowing-week-in-year-and-year)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See a test of this here: https://www.tehplayground.com/c2dOYxxwIa9LDscW

```
while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
$thedate = $row['Date'];
$dow = date('w', strtotime($thedate)); // the day of the week of the date - number based - zero is sunday
$dowsun = date('Y-m-d', (strtotime($thedate) - ($dow * 60*60*24))); // first day of that week (sunday)
$dowsat = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($thedate) + ((6-$dow) * 60*60*24)); // last day of that week (saturday)

/* for example:
   if $row['WEEK(Date)'] = "2021-06-08" which is a Tuesday
   $dowsun = "2021-06-06" which is a Sunday
   $dowsat = "2021-06-12" which is a Saturday
   with this answer you get the full week that contains the target date
*/
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$row['WEEK(Date)']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['Date']."</td>";
```

Comment: Im new to coding so I`m not sure if I understand how your code works. But how can I now display the last day of the displayed calendar week.  At the moment there is only displayed one date for example 2021-05-16. I want to display it like this: 2021-05-16 - 2021-05-22.

Comment: I updated the answer with explanations on what those values are

Comment: @Gandalfthegrey  - sorry there was an error. I updated the answer and provided a link to show that it works.

Comment: @Gandalfthegrey can you tell me what $row['WEEK(Date)'] equals? - give me one example so I can update my example link

Comment: Its the calendar week for example KW 19

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer to calculate based on `$row['Date']` which I assume is `YYYY-mm-dd` format